# Which vectors in $S_3$ belong to $span(S_1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, invariant-subspace

$ S_3 = \{w1, w2, w3, w4\}, w1   =  \left(\begin{array}\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ \end{array}\right),
w2   =  \left(\begin{array}\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ \end{array}\right), w3   =  \left(\begin{array}\ 0 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ \end{array}\right), w4   =  \left(\begin{array}\ 2 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{array}\right)$

$ S_1 = \{u1, u2, u3\}, u1   =  \left(\begin{array}\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ \end{array}\right),
u2   =  \left(\begin{array}\ 0 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ \end{array}\right), u3   =  \left(\begin{array}\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ \end{array}\right) $

(1) Is $ span(S_3)$ = $ R^4 $ ?

**$ \quad $ Yes, the linear system has no zero row, is an identity matrix, therefore it is always consistent.**

(2) $ Which\ of\ the\ vectors\ in\  S_3\ belongs\ to\ span(S_1)\ $ ?

**$ \quad \quad $ None (all linear systems are found to be inconsistent)**

(3) What is the intersection of $ span(S_3)\ and\ span(S_1) $ ?

**$ \quad \quad  span(S_3) \cap span(S_1)= R^4 \cap span(S_1) = span(S_1) $**

I am not sure if my answers are correct for **(2) and (3)**, if $S_3$ spans the entire $R^4$ space, would there not be at least some vectors that can be expressed as a linear combination of the vectors in $ S_1 $ for part (2), but the linear systems suggest otherwise? Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

(3) is correct.

The answer to (1) is correct (the span is all of $\Bbb R^4$), but I don't understand your justification—what is the identity matrix you refer to?

As for (2), I will trust your computations that none of the vectors in $S_3$ are in the span of $S_1$. As for the apparent paradox you noticed: your answer to (3) shows that lots of vectors in *the span of* $S_3$ are in the span of $S_1$, but that's not the same as saying that vectors from $S_3$ itself must be in the span of $S_1$.

For a simpler example, in $\Bbb R^2$: every vector in the span of $\{(1,0)\}$ is also in the span of $\{ (1,1) ,(1,-1) \}$, even though neither $(1,1)$ nor $(1,-1)$ is in the span of $\{(1,0)\}$.